improved line breaks for text which is slightly too long for a column
We have a table consisting of numbers and dates in the first three columns and text of varying length at the end. This works very well in principle:
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt, article]{memoir}
\usepackage[portrait,top=1.5cm,left=1cm,right=1cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{@{}rrrp{14.2cm}}
(1) & 3.50 h & 17.02.2023 & \lipsum[3-9][4]\\
(2) & 2.15 h & 18.03.2023 & \lipsum[10-15][4-5]\\
(3) & 1.20 h & 19.04.2023 & \lipsum[16-17][1]\\
(4) & 4.20 h & 20.05.2023 & \lipsum[18-20][4-5]\\
(5) & 7.45 h & 04.07.2023 & \lipsum[21-24][1-2]\\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}


However, if the text in the last column exceeds the space of the current line, the break occurs (as expected) such that the line is filled “to the maximum” (in the last column). But this is not a very pleasing effect in a table if the text in the last column is only slightly longer than what would fit in one row. In this particular case, a table entry rarely exceeds one line and entries, where the text in the last column does not fit, would benefit from a line break that ideally spreads the text on two lines with the second line being shorter - but not significantly shorter (a "ragged-left” look would be desirable with some kind of "balancing").
Is there an easy way to achieve something similar?
Many thanks in advance!

As always on the site, please extend to a full but minimal example so those who want to help only have to copy our example in order to test it. Here we have to add an entire doc in order to test.

>{\parfillskip=.75\linewidth}p{14.2cm}

As suggested by @daleif, I have edited the original question to include a full example (should have done that in the first place, sorry). Table entry (2) displays the (perceived) problem: I would prefer to have a line break before the second sentence instead of having just a few letters in the second line.

I have tried
\begin{tabular}{@{}rrr>{\parfillskip=.75\linewidth}p{14.2cm}}
which was suggested by @David Carlisle - but this is a very different effect, sorry.

Here I replace the last space with \nobreakspace and hyphenation of the last word is inhibited. Thus at least a fragment of the last-but-one word will be in the last line.
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt, article]{memoir}
\usepackage[portrait,top=1.5cm,left=1cm,right=1cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{collcell}

\usepackage[latin]{babel} % for hyphenation of lipsum text
\usepackage{lipsum}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\fixlastline}{m}
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tmpa_seq {~} {#1}
  \seq_pop_right:NN \l_tmpa_seq \l_tmpa_tl
  \seq_use:Nn \l_tmpa_seq {~}
  \nobreakspace \mbox{\tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl}
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{@{}rrr>{\collectcell\fixlastline}p{14.2cm}<{\endcollectcell}@{}}
(1) & 3.50 h & 17.02.2023 &
    Donec nonummy pellentesque ante. \\
(2) & 2.15 h & 18.03.2023 &
    Maecenas sapien libero, molestie et, lobortis in, sodales eget, dui. 
    Morbi ultrices rutrum lorem. \\
(3) & 1.20 h & 19.04.2023 &
    Nulla mattis luctus nulla. \\
(4) & 4.20 h & 20.05.2023 &
    Maecenas non sem quis tortor eleifend fermentum. Etiam id tortor
    ac mauris porta vulputate. \\
(5) & 7.45 h & 04.07.2023 &
    Etiam pede massa, dapibus vitae, rhoncus in, placerat posuere, odio.
    Vestibulum luctus commodo lacus. \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}


You risk underfull lines, though, so the cure might reveal worse than the disease.
If you're prone to use ragged right typesetting in the final column replace the code for \fixlastline with
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\fixlastline}{m}
 {
  \raggedright\arraybackslash % <--- for ragged right
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tmpa_seq {~} {#1}
  \seq_pop_right:NN \l_tmpa_seq \l_tmpa_tl
  \seq_use:Nn \l_tmpa_seq {~}
  \nobreakspace \mbox{\tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl}
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

(just one line added) to get, with the same input as before. The key is \arraybackslash that restores the meaning of \\ (which gets changed by \raggedright).


Many thanks for this elaborate suggestion! The problem with underfull lines could be mitigated by disabling the justified block alignment ("ragged-right"?) - is there a way to achieve this here with the right-most column?

@StefanVollmar Added the needed change

Excellent, thank you! This is what I had in mind - not something I could have come up with myself! - Although in many cases "ragged-right" typesetting will not be the first choice in layout, there is an important use case and it applies to my initial question: the table is being generated automatically by a database application (some sort of reporting). So nobody will look at the result and do any fine tuning (the kind you would normally expect in the context of a scientific paper etc) - and ragged-right (possibly without hyphenation) is "safer" for this kind of use case, I think.
